# what is a good java framework for building server applications?

Tags: java, frameworks

I want to code a server daemon application that provides some backend functionality. I'd like to stick to Java since I'm pretty familiar with this language and I figure it'd be much easier to just dig into a new framework and not a new language in parallel.

So far I found many promising frameworks, but all of them resemble somehow a webserver. Thing is, I don't want to code a web-application in terms of web-sites so I doubt that I'll need all the webserver-functionality such as templates and this stuff.

What would be a good suggestion for this purpose or would using a regular web-framework such as "play" without the template-stuff be the best choice?

Comment: Define `server application`. Will it be SOAP? REST? Raw TCP/IP packet communication? Some job it will do at time intervals? Maybe monitor some events? Basically your question sounds similar to "What is the best tool to build a living house?"

Comment: Daemon, web server, web application - which one are you focused on? In any case, voting to close as overly broad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JAX-WS is a standard for creating SOAP web services. Wikipedia [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_API_for_XML_Web_Services) to see what it is about.

For RESTful you would need to make http requests, usually get and post and this type of service works best if you develop a website. From what I understand you don't want this, but still if ever just check the spring framework.

Raw TCP/IP is so much harder and unless you know exactly what you want (performance and optimization wise) you`re better off using a framework.

Answer (score 0):

A webserver is used to implement webservices. A webserver may serve more than html to clients.

I have a personal "stack" using for a long time that is Jetty + RESTEasy and it serves no html at all (only XML and Json).

Answer (score 0):

Javascript + Rest (Glassfish + [Jersey](http://jersey.java.net) for rest). Glassfish – Java EE Full profile certified reference application server (server will used for REST host).